# how to make vuetify select drop down working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I working with vuetify but I have notice that v-select drop down menu is not working,I have tried to google but and end up with nothing,Please kindly assist on this. I will be appreciate,Thanks

```
<v-select label="City" items="items" ></v-select>

data:function(){ items:["Mumbai","Capetown"]}
```

Comment: <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="City"
        ></v-select>

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass ":items" instead of "items". By omitting the : in front of a property you are passing the prop as simple string.

Since you want it to be handled as object, you need to use ":item".

`<v-select label="City" :items="items"></v-select>`

Comment: Your data function should look like this `data() { return {items:['Mumbai', Capetown']}}`
Guess you are missing a `return` for the data object.

Comment: I have put return function still nothing seem to change

Comment: Please provide your entire code that is relevant for your question. Don't let us guess :)

Comment: <v-select
            :items="items"
            label="City"
            dense
            solo
          ></v-select>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Mumbai', 'Capetown'],
  }),
})